# Connectivity issues with Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I received a brand new computer and it is very powerful. It works very nicely with my latest games. However, there's just one problem: on this specific computer the Wifi connection, sometimes, and unpredictably, becomes unreliable. This is very annoying any times I want to play games online. Ping will suddenly jump from 12ms to 1-3s and then back, making it impossible to play, for example, io games on the internet.

I tried many different things, restarting the wifi, restarting the computer, updating to the latest drivers for the network card, nothing worked. Basically it sometimes randomly goes away and sometimes comes back. I know that this doesn't come from my Wifi box because I don't have this problem on other computers and mobile devices connecting through this Wifi box.

The network card is: Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz

The system configuration is: Microsoft Windows 11 Family 10.0.22621 Build 22621

Comment: What you have not appeared to have done, is test via a wired connection.

Comment: Could be a lot of things. It could be randomly swapping between the 5GHz and 2.5GHz bands, it could be trying a wider bandwidth and then falling back with a slightly marginal WiFi connection, it could be that your router supports *some* of the WiFi 6 spec which tricks your network card into trying something fancy and then spending time falling back when nothing works. There's a lot of people with problems on reddit but there also likely a lot more people *without* problems. https://www.google.com/search?q=Wi-Fi+6E+AX211+limit+to+5+site:www.reddit.com

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Upon looking on reddit, I found a suggestion which I applied. So far I didn't have any connectivity issues but I hope it will last. Here's what I did:
1) Open Device Manager

2) Expand the Network adapters section

3) Double-click the Intel AX211 adapter

4) Go to the Power management tab, if available

5) Uncheck the Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power

Comment: Unfortunately apparently the power management trick didn't work. I ended up with connectivity issues again today with random ping spikes. The same as usual. I tried forcing the channel to 5GHz and 2.5 GHz, I tried prevening trying to go on WiFi 6, none of this removed the issues. I even tried to switch off wifi from my phone, avoid using the phone close to the computer, switch off Bluetooth to prevent interferences, to no avail. I don't know what to do but simply accept that I have a shitty network card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for quite a while, I found [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3ahg59/fix_for_wireless_ping_spikes/) that fixed my ping spikes. Essentially, typing:

```
netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=no interface="Wi-Fi"
```

in a command line window solved the issue.